# Java swing 2D pixel based sprite class not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, sprite

I made me a pixel based sprite class for a simple game in java and swing, and I don't want to let some sprites go through other sprites. So I wrote two loops that are supposed to add the pixels of every other sprite to the "material" array of the level. **Material should not be passable. With the level it does work. There the sprite can't pass through its material. But with other sprites it doesn't. It can go through them. And that's the bug I actually want to fix. It seems that the sprites' pixel arrays *aren't* appended.**

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Code :

```
int applied_pixels=lvl.material.length;
Sprite[] others=new Sprite[] {other sprites};
/*EDIT : others[i].frameborders[others[i].frame].all is the point array of the sprites' pixels
others[i].frame is the frame of the sprite object, because they contain an array of BufferedImages. Frame is the one that should be taken*/
Level lvl=the level; //Containing a couple of point arrays of pixels of some types, for example containing the material array of pixels
int apply_pixels=0; //How many pixels are needed ?
for (int i=0; i < others.length; i++) {
     if (others[i] != null) { //Isn't the sprite null
         apply_pixels=apply_pixels+others[i].frameborders[others[i].frame].all.length; //How many points does it has to add ?
     }
}
level=lvl.clone(); //Copy level to be able to later append points to the material array
level.material=new Point[apply_pixels];
System.arraycopy(lvl.material,0,level.material,0,lvl.material.length); //Copy old material array points
int appending_position=0;
appending_position=lvl.material.length; //Which destination position to append the points at ?
for (int i=0; i < others.length; i++) {
     if (others[i] != null) { //Isn't the sprite null
         System.arraycopy(others[i].frameborders[others[i].frame].all,0,level.material,appending_position,others[i].frameborders[others[i].frame].all.length); //Copy the points from the sprite to the material array
         appending_position=appending_position+others[i].frameborders[others[i].frame].all.length; //Position to append at is now plus the length of appended points
     }
}
```

Comment: Without any context, the code you posted is completely meaningless. For example, we have no idea how you compute collisions, which is where the real problem seems to be.

Comment: I wanted to make it clear : The problem isn't there. Because then it wouldn't work with the points of the level.

Comment: The problem is : The points should be added, but because of probably any reference or something else they don't seem to be.

Comment: My point still stands: If you don't know what is actually going on, you will have to provide a whole lot more information before we can tell you what is happening.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `apply_pixels` seems to silently change to `applied_pixels`...

Comment: Your note is right. Edited it.

Comment: I dont know what information you do need anymore ?

Comment: I tested anything else, it does work. This code is the source of the bug. Almost everytime when I try to work with an array twice it fails...

Comment: Here's an example: What is `others[i].frame`? Why not provide us with some reference on the `Sprite` class you are using? Perhaps you are adding the wrong, or at least incomplete, pixels?

Comment: No, because its pixel based it wouldnt work with the level, that are the same  arrays which have to work. When I check collision with lava, with the same pixel array and the level lava pixel array, it does work. And, I edited my post : The sprite class contains an int called "frame". others[i] is another sprite.

Comment: And the frame indices which point array and which image of the image array to use, because the sprite should contain various images for animations etc.

Comment: As someone reading this from the outside (i. e. not intimately familiar with your code) , you have still not posted nearly enough useful information to understand the issue. Please make a habit of posting code with narrative into the question itself rather than making comments that have no real meaning to anyone but you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist : I am sure the bug is here. The other code wont be very clear for you and wont be helpful.

Comment: I see that I'm not getting through to you, but you will notice that there are three close votes against you and no sign of an answer or even comments besides my own. The reason you should consider being more receptive to my rfi is that you have no idea where the bug is, or you wouldn't be asking a question in the first place.

Comment: It's probably more productive to just let me see the code I'm asking for than to tell me I'm wrong when you are the one with the error asking for help. I am not implying that I'm right, just that you stand to lose nothing by satisfying my annoying curiosity and may even gain something by it. Also, don't worry about the code being a bit obscure. That's something we can work with, unlike the total absence of any meaningful information whatsoever, as you have now.

Comment: I cannot post that, its really a mess, nobody would like to see through my 1167 lines of code, so I assume that the error is here, and so I only posted this snippet

Comment: Cut it down to the relevant portions. I asked for a specific object. The error is most likely not in what you posted.

Comment: I had the same bug with sprites that should be "passable". When I only assigned to the array once, it worked. But here I'm not able to do this trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible problems with your code as posted.

The first is that `level.material=new Point[apply_pixels];` only allocates elements for the new pixels. It should probably read `level.material=new Point[lvl.material.length + apply_pixels];`. Alternatively, you can initialize `apply_pixels` as `int apply_pixel = lvl.material.length` instead of to zero.

The second problem is that you never show us how `lvl` replaces the original `level`. Presumably the code you posted is part of a method somewhere and `level` is an input that is passed in, but is accessed through a field by other parts of the program. Unless the modified `lvl` is correctly returned and replaces the original, the code here will have no effect. However, this is only speculation because OP refuses to post the relevant code.

Comment: `level=lvl.clone()`, my level implements Cloneable.

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: The  copying works fine, I perform all sprite operations on level, so the copying of the level seems to be not the problem

Comment: Little mistake : The  copying works fine, I perform all sprite operations on level, so the copying of the level doesnt seem to be the problem